# is there any way to identify Unique IDs of UIElements in a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I know we can use TAG to identify the elements. But I am creating a dynamic library which gets injected to other app on a jailbroken iPhone and starts scraping data. So using tag is no option for me since I dont have the control.

I see object ID in storyboard is uniques for all elements. but it is not accessible in code and we cant get the element using that.

The problem is when I try to reproduce users recorded action, I dont know which button he clicked (same for all other UIElemetns).

Is there any other way or identifiers for UIElements to access at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timestamp to get unique ID's and assign to your view later:

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeStamp];

myView.tag = timeStampObj;
```